# Use Microsoft Excel to import and refresh data from only some columns of a CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, database

I have a CSV that's 100+ MB, so it takes a long time to load.

In Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16, I'd like to use the "Get data" or a similar functionality to load data from that CSV into an Excel workbook that adds some logic on top of that data. I'd like the ability to easily refresh that source CSV data either automatically or with a single click.

But I'd only like to load a couple of specific columns from the source CSV, rather than all of its columns, which will hopefully help speed up the process.

All my Googling has led nowhere on this topic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried loading the file in Power Query, using Transform to edit the query, remove the columns you don't want... etc?

Comment: @FlexYourData, no, please feel free to submit a suggestion. I have not seen any Power Query abilities in Excel for Mac v16, nor has my Googling returned anything helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-in-excel-for-mac-power-query-7b2f337d-e7d2-4fdf-bf00-3dfbb1e5e9c5

Comment: Yes, Power Query is the way to go for your use case. Having said that learning to use it will take more than a short sentence or two on this site. I recommend you jumping on youtube to look for some basic tutorials that will get you started.

Comment: Power Query will help you: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/textcsv

Comment: Just another vote for power query (called "transform and get" in newer excel versions). PQ loads data directly into the data model, allows for transforming lots of data and only displays what needs to be seen. This would drastically reduce your loading time.